# Change countries boundaries color in a shapefile with R

Tags: shapefile, r, cartography

I am working with R to create a map with a shapefile.
I would like to change the color of the countries boundaries but I don't know how to do that.
Is it possible to change the color?

Here is my code:

```
world1 = readShapeSpatial("map.shp")
plot(world1)
```

I have a map with black boundaries and I would like to have grey boundaries.
If I write `plot(world1, col="grey")` it colors the countries and not the boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `border` argument in the `plot`-method:

```
plot(x, border="grey")

R> args(sp:::plot.SpatialPolygons)
function (x, col, border = par("fg"), add = FALSE, xlim = NULL, 
    ylim = NULL, xpd = NULL, density = NULL, angle = 45, pbg = NULL, 
    axes = FALSE, lty = par("lty"), ..., setParUsrBB = FALSE, 
    usePolypath = NULL, rule = NULL)
```